# Custom view with MutableContextWrapper VS fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, mutable-context-wrapper

I want to use 1 *view* instance in multiple `activities`. (Ignore the reason please) I am curious about the **advantages** and **disadvantages** of the following choices:

- **`MutableContextWrapper`** for the *Custom View* (for example: `RelativeLayout`) and switching `context` to another `activity` when that is shown. So, moving view from `activity` to `activity`.
- Using **`fragments`**.

Comment: Have you tested the feasibility of this? I mean, a `View` can have only a single parent at a time. I'd imagine that coordinating the detach/attach alone would be rather cumbersome for any non-trivial setup.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes. It seems like it is working and it is not preventing related activity from being destroyed. I keep the View in an outside singleton class which also keeps MutableContextWrapper. Whenever I need to attach that view to somewhere else, I remove the view from the parent first, then change the baseContext of that view's MutableContextWrapper. It works but this does not mean that it has no disadvantages, that is why I would like to hear about your experiences. (I know that keeping it in a singleton and not correctly managing it may easily cause leaks)

Comment: I need to do this in Flutter, to host a fragment in the View class that brings it to flutter app